# Can't add .NET3.5 to Windows 8.1 using DISM

Tags: windows-8, dism

The same command line that works fine on Windows 8 PCs doesn't work on Windows 8.1 PCs.

```
DISM.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\sxs
```

Which is where I copied the sxs folder to.

But according to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443.aspx) it should work on both 8 and 8.1. The progress bar stops at 65.8% with error: 0x800f0081f.

The source file could not be found.

But it definitely is at that location - copy and pasted to the address bar and it is there. I have a need to install .NET 3.5 this way to support offline installation of a .NET program, so the Control Panel - Windows Features method isn't an option for me.

I've made [the logs](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2611496/logs.zip) available for analysis. It seems that DISM on Windows 8.1 doesn't understand the /featurename:NetFx3 option, since the DISM.log has the line

```
Encountered an unknown option "featurename" with value "NetFx3" - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_GetPackagesFromCommandLine
```

Comment: Have you tried using DISM to verify your installation doesn't need to be repaired.  You are not alone with this problem http://superuser.com/questions/578767/cannot-activate-net-3-5-on-windows-8-cant-activate-from-control-panel-and-nev?rq=1 but I can confirm the command **does work**.

Comment: This is a freshly installed Windows 8-64 that was Windows Updated to latest and then updated to 8.1. I have done SFC /scannow and DISM with /scanhealth, /checkhealth and /restorehealth [as suggested](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/component-store-corruption-repair-windows-image). Best I can tell from [Technet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2012/05/14/windows-8-and-net-framework-3-5.aspx?PageIndex=3#comments) is that the source is invalid for this build. So where to get sxs folder for Windows 8.1?

Comment: I used a virtual machine and the Windows 8.1 installation media personally to confirm the command works.

Comment: have yo installed a MUI package (display language)?

Comment: No language packs added, its a UK English install DVD of Windows 8 that I started with and I haven't added anything. I also checked that no languages have been added in the control panel. It was activated before the Windows Updates and the 8.1 upgrade.

Comment: upload the folder *C:\Windows\logs\CBS* and the *DISM.log* from *C:\Windows\logs\DISM*

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have added a link to the logs in the question.

Comment: the log shows, that the files are missing: "Not able to pre-stage package: Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-AddOn-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~en-GB~6.3.9600.16384, file: shfusion.chm"

Comment: Not sure why any files would be missing as all I have done is clean install and upgrade as any user would do. I've just run Windows Update again, it didn't appear to make any changes and stil fails the DISM command.

Comment: I have the same problem.  the kb article for this problem does not contain anything that helps. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2734782

Answer (score 1):

The files in the SXS folder have to be the right ones for that version of Windows. It will not work with an SXS folder from the 8.0 disk when the PC has been upgraded to 8.1, then you need the SXS folder from an 8.1 disk. I didn't find this made clear anywhere in documentation and the error message "The source file could not be found" is at best misleading. However, the clue (if you already know the information below) is in the CBS log where the message about a file with a 6.3.9600 name is shown, since no files in an SXS folder from Windows 8.0 have such a filename.

**How to determine if your SXS folder is for Windows 8.0 or 8.1**

Almost all the folders in the SXS folder for Windows 8.0 contain the string "6.2.9200" in their foldername. Almost all the folders in the SXS folder for Windows 8.1 contain the string "6.3.9600" in their foldername. There are no cases of the string from one version being in any foldername of the other version.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling KB2966828 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just move argument `/limitaccess` as shown below or remove it.

```
DISM.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /Source:C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\sxs /LimitAccess
```

Answer (score 0):

While this is an old post I have been dealing with this issue this week. If you use SCCM offline servicing or a pre-configured WIM and your image contains the following KB:

KB2966826

KB2966826

KB2966826

The installation will fail regardless of what you do. These are .NET 3.5 security updates that get installed regardless of whether 3.5 is installed on the machine. If they exist they prevent offline installation.